# Passing Device Viewport size to Server for generating page

Tags: jquery, mobile, client-server

I would like to find out the most transparent way to pass the device viewport size (retrieved using jQuery $(window).width() / $(window).height()) to a server and use that to build a php page (in Codeigniter). I realize the server-size view is assembled *before* the JavaScript is executed on the client and that's exactly the dilemma... :)

Is there an elegant workaround that doesn't affect performance / usability too much?

Thanks!

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html

Comment: thanks for the comment. Unfortunately the user agent doesn't include the viewport size...